# How to display an understandable error from sqlite expo?

Tags: sql, reactjs, sqlite, react-native

I'm creating an app in React-native and I use expo-SQLite for the database.
Unfortunately, I have a problem in my db request and I don't understand the error sent from sqlite.

Could you please help me ?

This is my code:

```js
db.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql(
            `create table if not exists Espace (id_espace integer primary key autoincrement,name text not null unique)`, [], (tx, results) => {
                console.log("Create table Espace");
            }
        );
});
```

```js
db.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql(
            `INSERT INTO Indicator (title, display_order, type, hidden, graphic_type, id_espace) VALUES ('?','?','?','?','?','?')`, [title,display_order,type, hidden, graphic_type, espace], (_, {rows}) =>{
                  console.log('Put Indicator: ' + title + type + display_order + hidden + graphic_type + espace);
            },
            (error)=>{
                console.log(error);
                return true;
            }
        );
    });
```

When I try to create an indicator my console display this error from sqlite:

```
WebSQLTransaction {
  "_complete": false,
  "_error": null,
  "_running": true,
  "_runningTimeout": false,
  "_sqlQueue": Queue {
    "first": undefined,
    "last": undefined,
    "length": 0,
  },
  "_websqlDatabase": WebSQLDatabase {
    "_currentTask": TransactionTask {
      "errorCallback": [Function anonymous],  
      "readOnly": false,
      "successCallback": [Function anonymous],
      "txnCallback": [Function anonymous],    
    },
    "_db": SQLiteDatabase {
      "_closed": false,
      "_name": "diplea.db",
    },
    "_running": true,
    "_txnQueue": Queue {
      "first": Object {
        "item": TransactionTask {
          "errorCallback": [Function anonymous],
          "readOnly": false,
          "successCallback": [Function anonymous],
          "txnCallback": [Function anonymous],
        },
      },
      "last": Object {
        "item": TransactionTask {
          "errorCallback": [Function anonymous],
          "readOnly": false,
          "successCallback": [Function anonymous],
          "txnCallback": [Function anonymous],
        },
      },
      "length": 1,
    },
    "exec": [Function anonymous],
    "version": "1.0",
  }
```

It means nothing to me ... could you tell me a way to understand it? Or maybe what is wrong in my code ...

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the Transaction itself, not the error.

According to [Expo's SQLite docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/), the error callback of `Transaction.executeSql` takes two arguments:

> **error *(function)*** -- Called if an error occured executing this particular query in the transaction. Takes two parameters: the transaction itself, and the error object.

You want your error callback to look like this:

```js
tx.executeSql(
    ...,
    ...,
    ...,
    (_, error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return true;
    }
);
```

Comment: Suppose i got error message like this  in the console ' {"code": 0, "message": "UNIQUE constraint failed: Users.Email (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE[2067])"} ', how can i present meaningfully  to the end user such that  the email id already exist